# Importing data from mysql to druid

Tags: mysql, druid

I have been using mysql for all my data storage and querying. But as now the tables sizes has become so much high, it takes sometimes hours to get the results. I have taken every possible measures like optimizing queries and indexing the tables properly.

So I have been thinking of using druid. I have not worked with druid earlier. I think I have to import all the tables, data from mysql to druid. I cannot understand where should I start. So if anyone kindly helps me with any kind of guidance, I will be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone who needs info on performance comparisons between MySQL and Druid, see [the blog at druid.io](http://druid.io/blog/2014/03/12/batch-ingestion.html).

Answer (score 9):

First note that Druid ingests timeseries data, so each row of your data will have to have a timestamp. If that's possible, read on.

Output your data to CSV or TSV. Those are two of the formats supported for batch ingestion. So your data will look something like this:

`2013-08-31T01:02:33Z,"someData","true","true","false","false",57,200,-143

2013-08-31T03:32:45Z,"moreData","false","true","true","false",459,129,330

...`

Then you can create an [index task](http://druid.io/docs/0.6.52/Tasks.html) which has a firehose section where you specify the location of the file, format, and columns:

```
"firehose" : {
   "type" : "local",
   "baseDir" : "my/directory/",
   "filter" : "my.csv",
   "parser" : {
     "timestampSpec" : {
       "column" : "timestamp"
     },
     "data" : {
       "type" : "csv",
       "columns" : ["timestamp","data1","data2","data3",...,"datan"],
       "dimensions" : ["data1","data2","data3",...,"datan"]
     }
   }
 }
```

Note the special handling given to the timestamp column.

Now run the indexing service (the [Druid docs](http://druid.io/docs/latest/) contain info on how to start the cluster you'll need) and feed the task to it as described in the section [Batch Ingestion Using the Indexing Service](http://druid.io/docs/latest/Batch-ingestion.html). The data will be ingested and processed into Druid segments that you can query.

Comment: Is the above spec still correct  with latest version of druid?

Comment: what if I have multiple tables?

Comment: The latest version has docs giving an example of both the csv format and config.json used for ingesting [here](http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/data-formats.html).

Comment: no need to export data in CSV. Use SQL input ingestion https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/native-batch.html#sql-input-source

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i dont's think druid work better as a storage, it's more exact when we say that it's a realtime query and process tool.
moreover, i prefer to use hive+hdfs combo to replace your mysql since the size of your tables increasing. What's more, druid can take hdfs as its deep storage